# How to populate a ComboBox in C# from data structure containing US States?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, combobox, dropdownbox

the below link shows a class created for the use of a combobox.

[Standardized US States Array and Countries Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367529/standardized-us-states-array-and-countries-array)

```
static class StateArray
{

   static List<US_State> states;

   static StateArray()
   {
      states = new List<US_State>(50);
      states.Add(new US_State("AL", "Alabama"));
      states.Add(new US_State("AK", "Alaska"));
      states.Add(new US_State("AZ", "Arizona"));
      states.Add(new US_State("AR", "Arkansas"));
      states.Add(new US_State("CA", "California"));
      states.Add(new US_State("CO", "Colorado"));
      states.Add(new US_State("CT", "Connecticut"));
      states.Add(new US_State("DE", "Delaware"));
      states.Add(new US_State("DC", "District Of Columbia"));
      states.Add(new US_State("FL", "Florida"));
      states.Add(new US_State("GA", "Georgia"));
      states.Add(new US_State("HI", "Hawaii"));
      states.Add(new US_State("ID", "Idaho"));
      states.Add(new US_State("IL", "Illinois"));
      states.Add(new US_State("IN", "Indiana"));
      states.Add(new US_State("IA", "Iowa"));
      states.Add(new US_State("KS", "Kansas"));
      states.Add(new US_State("KY", "Kentucky"));
      states.Add(new US_State("LA", "Louisiana"));
      states.Add(new US_State("ME", "Maine"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MD", "Maryland"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MA", "Massachusetts"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MI", "Michigan"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MN", "Minnesota"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MS", "Mississippi"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MO", "Missouri"));
      states.Add(new US_State("MT", "Montana"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NE", "Nebraska"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NV", "Nevada"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NH", "New Hampshire"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NJ", "New Jersey"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NM", "New Mexico"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NY", "New York"));
      states.Add(new US_State("NC", "North Carolina"));
      states.Add(new US_State("ND", "North Dakota"));
      states.Add(new US_State("OH", "Ohio"));
      states.Add(new US_State("OK", "Oklahoma"));
      states.Add(new US_State("OR", "Oregon"));
      states.Add(new US_State("PA", "Pennsylvania"));
      states.Add(new US_State("RI", "Rhode Island"));
      states.Add(new US_State("SC", "South Carolina"));
      states.Add(new US_State("SD", "South Dakota"));
      states.Add(new US_State("TN", "Tennessee"));
      states.Add(new US_State("TX", "Texas"));
      states.Add(new US_State("UT", "Utah"));
      states.Add(new US_State("VT", "Vermont"));
      states.Add(new US_State("VA", "Virginia"));
      states.Add(new US_State("WA", "Washington"));
      states.Add(new US_State("WV", "West Virginia"));
      states.Add(new US_State("WI", "Wisconsin"));
      states.Add(new US_State("WY", "Wyoming"));
   }

   public static string[] Abbreviations()
   {
      List<string> abbrevList = new List<string>(states.Count);
      foreach (var state in states)
      {
         abbrevList.Add(state.Abbreviations);
      }
      return abbrevList.ToArray();
   }

   public static string[] Names()
   {
      List<string> nameList = new List<string>(states.Count);
      foreach (var state in states)
      {
         nameList.Add(state.Name);
      }
      return nameList.ToArray();
   }

   public static US_State[] States()
   {
      return states.ToArray();
   }

}
```

I created a class called USStates.cs from the above and dragged a combobox onto my form. This is a WinForm Application.
I'm not familiar with classes and how to reference it so that my combobox will populate the US States...would anyone be able to assist with this?

Is it something I would input in my combobox event?

```
private void cbState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//populate with US States from the USStates.cs class....
}
```

Comment: Is it a winform application or wpf?

Comment: The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is called when the user changes which item is selected. You want to add them to `cbState.Items`, and probably in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your static class StaticArray in the following way:

```
static class StateArray
{
    static List<US_State> states;

    static StateArray()
    {
        states = new List<US_State>(50);
        states.Add(new US_State("AL", "Alabama"));
        states.Add(new US_State("AK", "Alaska"));
        states.Add(new US_State("AZ", "Arizona"));
        states.Add(new US_State("AR", "Arkansas"));
        states.Add(new US_State("CA", "California"));
        states.Add(new US_State("CO", "Colorado"));
        states.Add(new US_State("CT", "Connecticut"));
        states.Add(new US_State("DE", "Delaware"));
        states.Add(new US_State("DC", "District Of Columbia"));
        states.Add(new US_State("FL", "Florida"));
        states.Add(new US_State("GA", "Georgia"));
        states.Add(new US_State("HI", "Hawaii"));
        states.Add(new US_State("ID", "Idaho"));
        states.Add(new US_State("IL", "Illinois"));
        states.Add(new US_State("IN", "Indiana"));
        states.Add(new US_State("IA", "Iowa"));
        states.Add(new US_State("KS", "Kansas"));
        states.Add(new US_State("KY", "Kentucky"));
        states.Add(new US_State("LA", "Louisiana"));
        states.Add(new US_State("ME", "Maine"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MD", "Maryland"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MA", "Massachusetts"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MI", "Michigan"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MN", "Minnesota"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MS", "Mississippi"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MO", "Missouri"));
        states.Add(new US_State("MT", "Montana"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NE", "Nebraska"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NV", "Nevada"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NH", "New Hampshire"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NJ", "New Jersey"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NM", "New Mexico"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NY", "New York"));
        states.Add(new US_State("NC", "North Carolina"));
        states.Add(new US_State("ND", "North Dakota"));
        states.Add(new US_State("OH", "Ohio"));
        states.Add(new US_State("OK", "Oklahoma"));
        states.Add(new US_State("OR", "Oregon"));
        states.Add(new US_State("PA", "Pennsylvania"));
        states.Add(new US_State("RI", "Rhode Island"));
        states.Add(new US_State("SC", "South Carolina"));
        states.Add(new US_State("SD", "South Dakota"));
        states.Add(new US_State("TN", "Tennessee"));
        states.Add(new US_State("TX", "Texas"));
        states.Add(new US_State("UT", "Utah"));
        states.Add(new US_State("VT", "Vermont"));
        states.Add(new US_State("VA", "Virginia"));
        states.Add(new US_State("WA", "Washington"));
        states.Add(new US_State("WV", "West Virginia"));
        states.Add(new US_State("WI", "Wisconsin"));
        states.Add(new US_State("WY", "Wyoming"));
    }

    public static List<US_State> States()
    {
        return states;
    }
}
```

Using your original List should be enough for you ComboBox DataSource to be populated as follow:

```
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Abbreviations";
this.comboBox1.DataSource = StateArray.States();
```

Assuming your US_State class looks like:

```
public class US_State
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviations { get; set; }

    public US_State(string abbreviations, string name)
    {
        Abbreviations = abbreviations;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several practical ways to populate ComboBox (or DropDownList) by binding it to various data structures, as detailed in the article: **Binding ASP.NET DropDownList to data structures** (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214418/Binding-DropDownList-to-various-data-structures)

Pertinent to your case, consider binding to Dictionary object containing US StateAbbreviations/States like shown in the following code snippets;

```
  // create sample dictionary object containing US StateAbbreviations/States
            Dictionary<string,> dictStates = new Dictionary<string,>();
            dictCountries.Add("AL", "Alabama");
            dictCountries.Add("AK", "Alaska");
            dictCountries.Add("AZ", "Arizona");
            // the rest of the list

            // Method 1a: Data Binding DropDownList  `ddl2DictionaryDataBind` to Dictionary using DataSource and DataBind()
            ddl2DictionaryDataBind.DataSource = dictStates;
            ddl2DictionaryDataBind.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddl2DictionaryDataBind.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddl2DictionaryDataBind.DataBind();
            ddl2DictionaryDataBind.ToolTip = "Data Bind to Dictionary using Value/Key";

            // Method 1b. Data Binding DropDownList `ddl2DictionaryBindValues` to Dictionary (either Keys or Values)
            // using DataSource property of the DropDownList object. This method will
            // render the <select> HTML element with option values and inner HTML
            // both corresponding to Dictionary Values (it could be bound to Keys instead)
            // note: this method requires System.Linq reference
            ddl2DictionaryBindValues.DataSource = dictStates.Values.ToArray();
            ddl2DictionaryBindValues.DataBind();
            ddl2DictionaryBindValues.ToolTip = "Data Bind to Dictionary using only Values";

            // Method 1c. Data Binding DropDownList `ddl2DictionaryLoop` to Dictionary using iterations:
            // looping through the dictionary items and adding them to the DropDownList
            // this method will render the <select> HTML element with option values 
            // corresponding to Dictionary Keys and inner HTML corresponding to Values
            // note: if Dictionary contains data types other than String (for example, Dictionary<int,>)
            // then add the ToString() conversion to that data type
            ddl2DictionaryLoop.ToolTip = "Bind to Dictionary (Key/Values) using iteration";
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,> _dictItem in dictStates)
            {
                ddl2DictionaryLoop.Items.Add(new ListItem(_dictItem.Value, _dictItem.Key));
            }
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: The core object of that class is a List containing StateAbbreviations/States. It's much more logical to use a Dictionary Object <string,string> (the code will be much cleaner). Or, to convert the List to 2d array and bind it as shown in the article. Or, to bind it to that List (see; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904274/how-can-i-databind-a-list-of-objects-to-a-dropdownlist-and-set-the-selectedite). Thanks and regards,

Comment: You are welcome Jae! Best of luck with your project. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the code you wanted, however you have gained nothing, so please read the provided links until you are comfortable with what you are doing

Put the following somewhere in your form, it assumes you have actually made the class you have pointed to

```
private void InitStates()
{
    cbState.BeginUpdate();
    foreach(var state in StateArray.Names)
    {
        cbState.Items.Add(state);
    }
    cbState.EndUpdate();
}
```

`BeginUpdate` can be read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx)

`foreach` can be read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

`ComboBox.Items` can be read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items(v=vs.110).aspx)

ComboBoxes in general can be read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there are many many examples

Comment: What do you mean by "you have gained nothing"? I'm getting a red squiggly line under "StateArray" stating the name does not exist in the current context...

Comment: Do you have a namespace inside your USStates.cs file?

Comment: If not you need to add a namespace, and reference it in the file your calling it from using the keyword "using"... this might help you out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_namespaces.htm

Comment: Yes, there is a namespace inside my USStates.cs which is "namespace CIS430". I did try adding the "using CIS430" in my main Form1.cs but the "StateArray" still does not exist....would you happen to know why...? Thanks Saruman...

Comment: Does the source compile without the above code, or with the above code commented out?

Comment: Yes, it does compile and I can click "Start" without the code. I can change the combobox to a textbox for a user to manually input the state but thought it would be easier to utilize the states class....apparently it isn't that easy...it doesn't help that I'm a newbie to C#

Comment: put public in front of that class, ie public static class StateArray

Comment: I already tried that...thanks for your help~ I'm just going to move on with a textbox for this sql database project...front end is just to test stored procs, triggers, functions etc

Answer (score 0):

You can get all states like this (using HtmlAgilityPack):

```
public void GetStates()
{
    var wc = new WebClient {Proxy = null};
    var webDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    webDoc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://goo.gl/2R4ne1"));

    foreach (var descendents in webDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Skip(1).Take(50)
        .Select(i => i.Descendants("td").ToList()))
        _allStates.Add(new State(descendents[0].InnerText, descendents[1].InnerText));
}
```

Other than that you can use this code that I wrote:

```
    private readonly List<State> _allStates = new List<State>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetStates();
        _allStates.ForEach(i => comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString()));
    }

    public void GetStates()
    {
        var wc = new WebClient {Proxy = null};
        var webDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        webDoc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://goo.gl/2R4ne1"));

        foreach (var descendents in webDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Skip(1).Take(50)
            .Select(i => i.Descendants("td").ToList()))
            _allStates.Add(new State(descendents[0].InnerText, descendents[1].InnerText));
    }

    public class State
    {
        public State(string ab, string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Abbreviation = ab;
        }

        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Name, Abbreviation);
        }
    }
```

I got the values to load on a Button Click event, but you can put

```
GetStates();
_allStates.ForEach(i => comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString()));
```

Under wherever you want