# Selecting value that binded to a dropdownlist in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I used this code to bind both value and text to DataValueField and DataTextField of a dropdownlist in C# as follows.

```
private void fillCombo()
{
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    Ds = BL.fillCombo();
    if(Ds.Tables.Count>0)
    {
        cboDesg.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
        cboDesg.DataValueField = Ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;
        cboDesg.DataTextField = Ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName;
        cboDesg.DataBind();
    }
}
```

but when I tried to select an item from this dropdownlist then only the very first value is getting selected always. I used the following code.

```
String empDsg = cboDesg.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Give me a suggestion.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5904318/5174469) does that help you?

Comment: i think your page getting updated every time and selects default value. Are you using update panels? where are you trying to get value can you share whole function? one more question are you trying to Set or Get the value?

Comment: YES That was the problem. I failed to make the !Ispostback check. Thank You guys

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure page is not getting post back or use update panel.

To set dropdownlist according to value:

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection(); //to clear previous selection
dropdownlist.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

To get dropdownlist selected value:

```
string textvalue = DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
```